# Converting a ruby hash to another collection

Tags: ruby

```
atts = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
}
```

Which should then produce the following:

```
custom_atts = {
    "key1" => {
    string_value: "value1",
    data_type: "String"
    },
    "key2" => {
    string_value: "value2",
    data_type: "String"
    }
}
```

So I want to create a function that will convert atts into custom_atts.

```
def custom_atts(atts)

end
```

I can loop through hash values like this:

```
h.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  value.each do |k,v|
    puts k
    puts v
  end
end
```

But not sure how to create a hash with a hash in it, while in a loop.

Comment: you use `map` to do such things in ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
atts = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
}

def custom_atts(atts)

  Hash[ atts.keys.map { |key|
          [ key, {
              string_value: atts[key],
              data_type: "String" } ] } ]

end

puts custom_atts(atts).inspect

# {:key1=>
#  {:string_value=>"value1", 
#   :data_type=>"String"}, 
#  :key2=>{
#    :string_value=>"value2", 
#    :data_type=>"String"}}
```

If your new keys should be strings instead of symbols, then change `key` to `key.to_s` inside the map.

Comment: It's possible that someone downvoted because the keys of `atts` are symbols but the desired result has those keys converted to strings.

Comment: ... which is what the optional `to_s` in the end is for; also, really, I believe the question whether it is a symbol or string is not the primary reason for asking this question. ;) Love Ruby for its expressiveness, being able to make such short solutions.

Comment: Yeah, no biggie, it was nice to have an accepted answer with *0* net votes. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
atts.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k.to_s] = { string_value: v, data_type: v.class } }
  #=> {"key1"=>{:string_value=>"value1", :data_type=>String},
  #    "key2"=>{:string_value=>"value2", :data_type=>String}}
```